# logstash is not fetching data from log file

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

logstash is configured with elasticsearch which should store data coming from logstash. configuration has been done properly still not fetching.

```
    input {
     file {
        path => "C:\Users\vishadub\Documents\elkstackTools\logs\error_log.log"
        type => "error_logs"
        start_position => beginning
        sincedb_path => "C:\Users\vishadub\Documents\elkstackTools\sincedb-access"
        }
     }

    output {
      elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
        index => "error_log"
        }
    }

    this is written in my config file..
    o/p is below====

    C:\Users\vishadub\Documents\elkstackTools\logstash-6.4.2\bin>logstash -f logstash.conf 
    Sending Logstash logs to C:/Users/vishadub/Documents/elkstackTools/logstash-6.4.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties [2018-10-30T11:35:39,167]
    [WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
    [2018-10-30T11:35:39,667][INFO ][logstash.runner] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.4.2"} [2018-10-30T11:35:41,645][INFO ][logstash.pipeline] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
    [2018-10-30T11:35:42,020][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}} [2018-10-30T11:35:42,036][INFO][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch]
Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://localhost:9200/, :path=>"/"}[2018-10-30T11:35:42,208][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] 
Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}[2018-10-30T11:35:42,286][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
    [2018-10-30T11:35:42,301][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
    [2018-10-30T11:35:42,348][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost:9200"]}
    [2018-10-30T11:35:42,380][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
    [2018-10-30T11:35:42,426][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
    [2018-10-30T11:35:42,861][INFO ][logstash.pipeline ] 
    Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"3 <Thread:0x45c02cea run>"} [2018-10-30T11:35:42,908][INFO ][logstash.agent] 
    Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]} [2018-10-30T11:35:42,940][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ] START,creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections [2018-10-30T11:35:43,221][INFO ][logstash.agent ] 
Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

Comment: Can you try running logstash using `--log.level debug` ? Maybe it will show what it's doing ? Should beginning in `start_position => beginning` enclosed in double quotes ?

Comment: From the log line it does appear main pipeline is running. `Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]} [2018-10-30T11:35:42,940][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ] START,creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections`. Is sincedb_path file `sincedb-access` getting updated ?

Comment: No sincedb-access file is not getting updated.

Comment: Try running logstash with debug log level and see if it shows anything helpful